# macro photography with rings and reverse lens

Tags: macro

For macro photos I try to use extension rings or reverse lens with my Panasonic gx9 camera. I  have a 12-60 lens. When I try with either method to take a photo I succeed to get focus only when I use the narrowest ring(7mm) and only when the lens touches or almost touches the object and then it cast shadow so I get not very nice rather dark photo. Shall I use a different lens or there is another solution?
Thanks
Shlomo

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/97517/what-kind-of-lens-to-photograph-a-1-mm-object/97534#97534

Comment: What focal length on the zoom are you using?  Try zooming in.  The longer focal length should increase working distance.