# 120mm with 35cm minimum focus distance for Macro?

Tags: macro, focal-length, minimum-focus-distance

Is 120mm focal length with 35cm minimum focus distance good/close enough for macro insect photography?

Comment: This is just https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/132791/canon-50mm-f1-8-and-canon-m50-4k-for-macro recast with less information. Why don't you just try it? Stick a pin through a raisin & see what it looks like when you try photograph it.

Comment: @tetsujin whats the point of this forum then

Comment: a) Stack Exchange is not a forum, it's a question and answer site. b) We can only answer answerable questions. the more information we have to work with, the more likely an accurate answer can be found. This has 'not enough information'. We also like questions to be well-researched, not just a poke in the dark hoping someone else can do the work for you. Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help) especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Once again - **you do not have 120mm focal length**, you have a 50mm lens.

Comment: good/close enough? For what? Only you can decide if it is good enough / close enough. Remember that focal length does not change through cropping - only angle of view does. The reason people talk about _equivalent_ focal lengths is **only** to have an idea of the angle of view in terms that they understand; the focal length itself is _not_ changing. For macro photography, you would really need a lens with high magnification factor: 0.5x might be acceptable, 1.0x would be better. What magnification factor does your lens offer? (That's a rhetorical question.)

Comment: In my opinion, the initial question should be reopened. The other question has the real details. An answer can clarify the concepts for the user. The comments on this question are assuming the info of the other post, but newer readers have no reference of the "50mm lens".

Comment: @Rafael the OP deleted the original question.

Comment: Even this one as it is, can be answered by helping the user understand the concepts. @Redsbefall Take a look at this: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/97517/what-kind-of-lens-to-photograph-a-1-mm-object/97534#97534

Answer (score 1):

Magnification (how does size of image compare with real life size) M = lens to image distance divided by lens to object distance. All values in millimeters M = 120 / 350 = 0.3. This tells us that the image will be approximately 1/3 life-size.